# Database Connection Exception after a period of inactivity on a web application built with hibernate 3 and struts 2(SQL Error: 17410, SQLState: 08000)

Tags: hibernate, c3p0, weblogic12c, oracle12c

i have an exception every morning when i want to authenticate to web application that uses `hibernate 3`, i have searched for problem like solutions in stackoverflow and i used `c3p0` to avoid this exception, but now im not sure if the problem is in `hibernate` configuration or in database server, i workaround the problem by redeploying the war file in `Weblogic`,

**the persistence.cfg.xml configuration is :**

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">30</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
<property  name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="oracle.jdbc.allowedLogonVersion">12</property>
```

the platform are (Oracle 12c, Weblogic 12c),

**the message of exception is :**

```
janv. 15, 2016 10:42:42 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
AVERTISSEMENT: SQL Error: 17410, SQLState: 08000
<15 janv. 2016 10 h 42 WET> <Warning> <org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter> <BEA-000000> <SQL Error: 17410, SQLState: 08000>
janv. 15, 2016 10:42:42 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
GRAVE: Il n'y a plus de données à lire dans le socket
<15 janv. 2016 10 h 42 WET> <Error> <org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter> <BEA-000000> <Il n'y a plus de données à lire dans le socket>
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2231)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
        at persistance.BaseDAO.getListObject(BaseDAO.java:131)
        at dao.UserDao.listeUsers(UserDao.java:11)
        at presentation.LoginAction.login(LoginAction.java:35)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:511)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Il n'y a plus de données à lire dans le socket
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:456)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:397)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1808)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
        ... 76 more
could not execute query
```

Thanks

Comment: Your c3p0 config isn't taking: hibernating is interacting directly with the Oracle driver, not with c3p0-managed proxies. You might try adding `<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>`. You'll also want to configure [Connection testing](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing). This could be as simple as `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>` [Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-connection-pool-configuration-with-c3p0-example/)

Comment: i'm going to make these changes and see the result, another question i use only hibernate-c3p0-3.6.3.Final.jar, must i add also the c3p0-oracle-thin-extras.jar and mchange-commons-java.jar ?

Comment: it is unlikely that you need `c3p0-oracle-thin-extras.jar`. but if you are using c3p0, you will need both c3p0's jar file and an mchange-commons-java.jar file as well. nowadays this is usually taken care of by automatic dependency management in some form or another. if you are manually setting up dependencies, download [from Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/?source=directory) the latest binary version of c3p0. you'll find both jars you need in the lib directory.

Comment: so that's why c3p0 doesn't work for me i have add just hibernate c3p0.jar in the build path, so after adding the c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar and mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar the problem is resolved with the following configuration in persistence.cfg.xml :

Comment: <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
         <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">70</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">500</property>
    
    <property name="c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1 from dual</property>

Comment: thanks for the support